# maven assembly plugin including jars dependencies and external files

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to use the Assembly plugin to include the dependecies as well as

Here is my assembly plugin

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-executable-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>

                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>
                                    jar-with-dependencies
                                </descriptorRef>  
                                   </descriptorRefs>
                                   <descriptors>
                                       <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                                   </descriptors>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                   <mainClass>com.sarm.myproject.XMLParser.LPUnMarshaller</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

here is my assembly.xml descriptor, i made the id same as the descritpor ref as it was creating a different jar for this descriptor. So i have two descriptors one is a jar-with-dependencies descriptor ref and one is the below descriptor, in this case what is happening is that it creating two jars and the second jar overwrites the previous jar. How is it possible to include these two in the same jar.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>


    <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.xml</include>
      </includes>

  <excludes>
        <exclude>30000dests.xml</exclude>

      </excludes>

    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${basedir}/test</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>*.xml</include>
      </includes>

    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Edit: I have tried some other approaches and i have seen that if i use the assembly.xml as a descriptor, a new jar is created along side any other default jar that is created as well. So i end up with two jars. The default jar is an executable like the jar plugin is configured. even though the assembly plugin is configured to have a manifest.mf with my main class name the jar created thru the assmbly.xml is not executable and has a folder of my projects name with the executable jar inside it.

I use mvn clean install to build my project and the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You should create two modules that produce two jars. Typically maven is going to produce one jar file per module with the module name as the jar name.
Maven recommends that each module have a single output artifact.

If you have concerns about duplicating code. You can inherit relevant stuff by have a parent pom.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The idea was to have one jar only. With dependencies AND the external files as well. Two jars, one having libs and one having external only and second one not even having the classes, they wont really help me much. I will run only jar. Also, the jars come in exploded form. If I use the assembly.xml with dependencysets THEN i can have jars, but then I miss out on the code. Why does the compiled classes not get packaged with the jar that is created with assembly.xml. I really liked the idea of using the assembly.xml it is so flexible.